# What is the meaning of Stacy words about her lover Patrick character?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pun

> Stacy: **He must have used the costumes to make real monsters, which
>   implies He needs the costumes to make the monsters, which implies He
>   already had a Ghost costume somehow, which implies
>   Patrick's the one.**
>
> Stella: Stacy's in love.
>
> Stacy: No, I mean the one. The bad guy.

What is the meaning of Stacy words here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quote is paraphrased from *Scooby Too 2 - Monsters Unleashed* [here](http://www.cswap.com/2004/Scooby-Doo_2:_Monsters_Unleashed/cap/en/25fps/a/00_47#caption)

All she is trying to do is deduce who the **bad guy** is through a logical train of thought. Beginning with the *ghost costume* and tracing back to where they are during the conversation, which seems to be a Costume Museum.

Inorder to make a real monster, he needed costumes
Patrick already had a monster costume, so he must be the **bad guy**